# How to implement Tiktok like video streaming and video scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to replicate the TikTok app UI with Flutter. Can anyone suggest to me how to replicate the video streaming/scrolling feature of the TikTok app in fluter? Till now I manage to Stream videos by embedding in PageView.builder() library. I am facing some problems for:

- Streaming videos like Tiktok.
- Videos are not loading properly.
- Scrolling like TikTok App
- Camera filters

Here is what I have done till now :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EA1eykmlwJeJr6B-WFsuV87Yp-vgihPC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I thing that your problem it's more like related to the video streaming, isn't it? Are you using HLS?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

i am working on a similar system in my flutter app.
Basically I used video_player plugin with caching feature, You can get it this way. Put this in your Puspec.yaml.

```
video_player:
git:
  url: https://github.com/999eagle/plugins.git
  ref: feature/caching
  path: packages/video_player
```

Then use PageBuilder and make a system to load and unload videos from memory while scrolling.

Comment: is video_player has caching feature??!!

Comment: Not officially, Someone forked it and added the feature

Comment: oh okay thanks ,, How can i read about this . do you have something to read?